# Pandas DataFrame with calculated values based on multiple dates

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with multiple stock data over multiple days.  I am trying to create a function that will add a column that makes a calculation based on multiple days in that time period.

For example:

```
df["pct_change"] = df["Close"].pct_change()
```

I can use this code to find the percent change but when I move from one stock to another in my database, it adds incorrect data.

I'll run into a similar issue if I try to calculate a moving average.  I can't seem to find documentation on how I would even pull the data to calculate that.

I can do this all in excel but it doesn't really help me with trying to code a program.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `groupby` to separate the stocks. For example, given the following data frame:

```
  Symbol       Date      Close
0      A 2020-04-01  69.494975
1      A 2020-04-02  11.764600
2      A 2020-04-03  22.382115
3      A 2020-04-04   7.099392
4      A 2020-04-05  13.491031
5      B 2020-04-01  28.769666
6      B 2020-04-02  19.311902
7      B 2020-04-03  29.691157
8      B 2020-04-04  94.667138
9      B 2020-04-05  98.194202
```

To calculate the percentage change:

```
df['pct_change'] = df.groupby('Symbol')['Close'].transform(lambda col: col.pct_change())
```

Comment: That did exactly what I was looking for with the percent change.  Looking into the `groupby().transform()` function, I was able to answer the rest of my question.. [https://pbpython.com/pandas_transform.html](https://pbpython.com/pandas_transform.html)